Is there a way to do a like join on two columns based on only the first 3 characters of one of the columns?
Table1



Column A
Column B




0001
AMP^


0002
JUN^


003
RES^



Table2



Column A
Column B




AMY JONES
AMPLITUDE


JUNE SMITH
JUNEBUG


HARRY LOO
HAR^



I want to join these two tables on column B in both tables, but when I do a like nothing comes back and I think it is because of the ^ character and I'm not sure how to get around this.
SELECT
    Table1.*,
    Table2.*
FROM
    Table1
LEFT JOIN
    Table2 ON Table1.column_B LIKE CONCAT(Table2.column_B, '%')

This is what I want to get back:



Column A
Column B




AMY JONES
AMPLITUDE


JUNE SMITH
JUNEBUG



I do apoligize if this is sloppy but I am a new student to SQL so am not entirely versed on the ins and outs yet. Thank you in advance for your help

You are correct that ^ is what is causing the problem. What you do about it depends on your data and what you want. Is ^ pure junk, meaning you can just remove it with a replace(). Or is it a wildcard placeholder which could occur anywhere meaning blah^yada in table1.column_b should match blahsomethingyada in table2.column_b

Wouldn't just join on the first three characters work for you?
SELECT
    Table1.*,
    Table2.*
FROM
    Table1
LEFT JOIN
    Table2 ON SUBSTR(Table1.column_B, 1, 3) = SUBSTR(Table2.column_B, 1, 3)


Risky assumption.
